# How to define lifetimes properly in closure

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
impl Rate for Vec<VolumeRanged> {
    fn costs<'a, I>(&'a self, issues: &I, period: u32) -> Box<'a + Iterator<Item = f32>>
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item=f32>,
        I::IntoIter: 'a
    {
        fn issue_cost(issue: f32, percentage: f32, constant: f32, max: f32) -> f32 {
            let r = issue * percentage / 100.0 + constant;
            match r.partial_cmp(&max) {
                Some(Less) => r,
                _ => max
            }
        }
        Box::new(issues.into_iter().map(|i| {
            let (pr, nr) = pairwise(self)
                        .find(|&(_, n)| in_range(&i, &n.range))
                        .expect("No range found");
            issue_cost(
                i,
                nr.percentage,
                pr.map_or(0.0, |x| x.max),
                nr.max,
            )
        }))
    }
}
```

Rust is saying

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:43:41
   |
43 |         Box::new(issues.into_iter().map(|i| {
   |                                         ^^^ may outlive borrowed value `self`
44 |             let (pr, nr) = pairwise(self)
   |                                     ---- `self` is borrowed here
   |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
43 |         Box::new(issues.into_iter().map(move |i| {
   |                                         ^
```

But I don't want to move ownership into closure. What I want is that returned boxed iterator should live as long as both `self` and `issues`. As soon as they go away - it should go away.

I know that this can be solved by passing cloned iterator to `issues` instead of a reference to it, I don't think that It's needed here.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=032ed5fe2896dd6eaef4ae63d6c3e72b&version=stable)

Answer (score 1):

Add `move` to the closure. `self` has type `&Vec<VolumeRanged>`, so closure will not take ownership of the vector, it will capture the reference to the vector.

Comment: It's the closure that should live as long as `issues` and `self`, not the other way around.

Comment: Lifetime annotations don't change actual lifetimes. Adding `move` will prevent you from having a reference to deallocated vector, that's all. Not adding `move` will not allow a program to compile, because closure captures reference to the function parameter `self`, which exist only inside a function.

Comment: why move `i` which comes from `issues` if the problem is with `self`?

Comment: besided have you tried that? Is will result in another error.

Comment: `i` is a closure parameter, it isn't affected by `move`. Another error (cannot move out of borrowed content) isn't directly related to your question. `into_iter()` tries to consume `*issues`, but it cannot move out of borrowed content. Replace `&I` with `I` to get rid of it.